# Отделение запятой наречия "Вчера"

Tags: пунктуация, наречия

Сходил в библиотеку – набрал школьных учебников, вчера.

"Вчера" примыкает к "сходил". Стоит ли его отделять запятой?

Comment: А ее – это кого?

Comment: "Вчера" примыкает к "сходил"?  В каком смысле?

Comment: "Вчера" относится к первой части предложения, так как "набрать школьных учебников" — более частное действие, чем "сходить в библиотеку". В первую очередь "вчера" должно относиться к общему, а потом уже, следовательно, к частному.

Answer (score 1):

Правильная мысль, и редактор, наверное, исправил бы все предложение на вариант:

> Вчера сходил в библиотеку и набрал школьных учебников.

Comment: При такой правке не тот смысловой оттенок.  Не обозначен присоединительный характер наречия, как, вероятно, задумано у автора.

Comment: Такое на письме допустимо разве что при документальной транскрипции, когда говорящий добавил это слово "вдогонку". Да, редактор исправил бы порядок слов, будь это чисто авторский текст.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит отделить **скобками**:

*Сходил в библиотеку – набрал школьных учебников **(вчера).***

Других вариантов для такой структуры предложения не предвидится.

Answer (score 0):

При такой структуре предложения, думаю, нужно поставить точку, то есть оформить как присоединительную конструкцию.
Наречие "вчера" разъясняет — когда именно? Вчера [сходил].

Присоединительными могут быть как главные, так и второстепенные члены предложения: *Пойду-ка посижу у себя. **Оденусь*** (Н. И.); *Смотрю, в одиннадцатой роте сигналы учат. **Хором*** (Купр.); *У Елены беда тут стряслась. **Большая*** (Панф.).

[Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120)

Представим себе такой диалог.

— И чем же ты занимался?
— Сходил в библиотеку — набрал школьных учебников. Вчера. Утром покатался на лыжах, потом сел заниматься.