# Как лучше: красота мира или красота земли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Нужно проверить предложение:

*...наслаждение от прогулки под горку, вниз, вниз и вниз, через прекрасный сосновый лес, сквозь который **просвечивали картины заката**, наполнили сердце радостью. **Красота мира** – величайший из лекарей.*

Почему красота ***мира***, если дается описание природы? Может быть, красота земли? Или всё равно?

А **"просвечивали картины заката"** – нормально?

Спасибо.

Comment: Прогулки под горку; прекрасный сосновый лес; величайший из лекарей... А это нормально?

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что это  образцовый текст. Если есть стилистические или грамматические ошибки, то надо указать, в чем они заключаются, а не просто править. Я же не могу всё переписать.

Comment: А я не понимаю, почему *наслаждение наполнил**и** сердце радостью.* Или там до многоточия что-то добавляется к этому наслаждению?

Comment: Поймите правильно: работа с фрагментами текста (по аналогии с тамошними проблемами Г. Аванесовой) в отрыве от полного объёма текста — напрасный труд. Более того, это не формат для нашего форума.

Comment: Артем, спасибо за ваше замечание, это нужно исправить.

Comment: А вот насчет фрагментов не очень понятно. Здесь я хотя бы контекст даю, а другие авторы вопросов иногда полпредложения предлагают,  иногда что-то фотографируют или пишут нечто невнятное. Как же всё это соответствует формату вашего форума?  Да и корректоры сюда частенько заглядывали со своими вопросами, никого это не удивляло. Тем не менее я прислушаюсь к вашему мнению и больше таких вопросов задавать не буду. С другой стороны, мне бы хотелось чтобы другие участники также рамки форума соблюдали.

Comment: Интересно, а вот этот вопрос корректен, он в рамках форума?  Предложение неестественное, придуманное автором, непонятно что и о чем.  И ведь отвечают на него. Никто его не закрывает и даже не редактирует.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458402/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: *я прислушаюсь к вашему мнению* — Это Вы напрасно, я считаю. Настоящая редакторская работа — самая интересная часть контента форума. Конечно, не у всех есть опыт редактирования, поэтому такие вопросы не всем будут интересны. Но если оставить на форуме только такие вопросы, которые будут интересны абсолютно всем, тогда здесь не будет ни одного вопроса. Заодно отмечусь своим мнением — обе метафоры воспринимаются вполне нормально.

Comment: «Интересно, а вот этот вопрос корректен, он в рамках форума?» Он странный, но от души. По этому вопросу ясно, что Вы не поняли что было сказано, а мысль проста: предложение редактировать текст подобные произведения есть просьба выполнить домашнее задание. В том и не совсем формат: задание есть, — промежуточных результатов своих усилий нет.

Comment: Хорошо, я поняла вас. Вы считаете, что это практически выполнение домашнего задания. Но я так не считаю. То же самое можно сказать про любой вопрос. Пусть тогда все объясняют,  откуда у них интерес к теме: от души или по какой-либо необходимости. Будем тогда отвечать только на душевные вопросы, я не против.  Впрочем, это тема не для личной беседы: я полагаю, что надо спросить у модераторов.  пусть они мне объяснят, что не так с моими вопросами, на которые люди отвечали заинтересованно, как мне кажется.

Comment: Посмотрела свой послужной список: 4100 ответов за 4 года.   Представляю, сколько неучтенных домашних заданий было выполнено. А уж сколько усилий затрачено.

Comment: @shampar домашние задания (даже если этот вопрос таковым считать) не запрещены в сообществе. Не допускаются вопросы типа "Сделайте за меня", но если вопрос "Проверьте правильно ли сделано", то он вполне допустим.

А вообще подобные проблемы лучше обсуждать на [Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: «Если вопрос "Проверьте правильно ли сделано", то он вполне допустим.» Марк Из♦ Вполне допустим вопрос: "Проверьте, правильно ли сделанное мною". Подобные проблемы обсуждались, и не было нужды их поднимать здесь. С этим согласен.

Answer (score 3):

Всё здесь в порядке.

*сквозь который просвечивали картины заката* || Это художественное выражение, образное, вполне приличное. Для описания природы самое то. И конечно, неординарное. А такое читать интересней.

*Красота мира – величайший из лекарей.* || А вот это звучит философски. Здесь взято в глобальном аспекте - не только лишь той природы, что описывается, а всего красивого, что есть в мире. Можно сказать в общем, что лечит всё то, что прекрасно. Предложение звучит очень пафосно - это круто.

А вот "*от прогулки под горку*" как-то не очень. Но об этом не спрашивается.

Answer (score 1):

[*Прекрасный лес*](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)— используемое словосочетание. И уже не важно, какой он, этот лес — сосновый, березовый или тундровый.
*Жили мы в прекрасном лесу, среди сосен и орешников, вместо занятий дремали полдня на полянках в отдалении от войны* (Д. Самойлов).

Если можно [*идти под горку*](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83), то что же мешает просто прогуляться — вниз, под уклон?

*Просвечивали картины заката* — интересно, объяснимо. Если мы стоим, то картина, конечно же, одна. Но мы же движемся (вниз, вниз и вниз), поэтому перспектива постоянно меняется — как в замедленном калейдоскопе. Красиво!

[Мир](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Mir-10557.html)
4. Всё, реально существующее на Земле, проявляющееся в её жизни.
Получается, что [красота мира](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&startyear=1983&lex2=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=2003&mode=main&parent1=0&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&p=0) "равна" [красоте земли](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8)? Не думаю.

*Все вызывало в нем восторг ― и то, как, покачивая бедрами, стюардессы катили по проходу столик с крошечными бутылочками, и то, что где-то внизу, изумрудно просвечивая сквозь облака, проплывали неизвестные ему ранее острова, и то, что на его груди болтался новенький «Полароид», которым фермер предполагал запечатлеть ожидаемую красоту мира* (Е. Евтушенко).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Ваши ответы всегда  интересные и познавательные. Меня заинтересовало слово "прекрасный", так как по нему мнения неоднозначные. Возможно, задам по этой теме отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Авторский вариант (как мне кажется) можно улучшить заменой: «просвечивали картины» - на «сочились цвета», «радостью» - на «легкостью», «лекарь» - на «целитель» / «врачеватель».
Вместо «величайший», что слишком близко к «знаменитый и недоступный», будет лучше использовать слово «искуснейший», т.е., владеющий методами более тонкими, чем «таблетка» или «хирургическое вмешательство».
И еще. Эти две (авторские) строки перегружены «прекрасной красотой». По моему ощущению удаление слова «прекрасный» улучшит исходный текст в большей степени, чем его замена любым из определений: «роскошный» / «ласкающий глаз/взгляд» / «ни с чем не сравнимый» / «живописный» / «сказочный» или аляповатейшим из всех, - «умопомрачительный»…

Comment: Спасибо, интересное мнение. Я его обязательно учту.